# read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable when calling scripts using case in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a menu that allows a user to call certain shell scripts in a the current directory. The menu loops until the user exits the script (entering 5)

Here is my code so far:

```
until [ "$SELECTION" = "5" ]; do    
echo "# Enter a number to launch:"                            
echo "# 1) Script 1"
echo "# 2) Script 2"
echo "# 3) Script 1 and Script 2"
echo "# 4) Readme"
echo "# 5) Exit"
echo -n "Launch: "
read SELECTION
case $SELECTION in
    1) 
    (exec "./script1") ;;
    2) 
    (exec "./script2") ;;
    3)
    (exec "./script1")
    (exec "./script2") ;;
    4) vi "readme.txt" ;;
    5) exit 0 ;;
    *) echo "Error. Please enter a valid selection." ;;
    esac
done
```

After the user selection, the selected script runs fine but once it is done, I get an error that just repeats:

```
read: read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And it never returns to the menu.
Im not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas? This is in bash.

Comment: What's in `script1` and `script2` that your are running 2 subshells deep? Why are you using `exec` and not calling the scripts with `bash ./script1`?

Comment: change `exec` to `sh` or `bash` then trype ur script in a full extension something like `script1.sh`

Comment: This question was obviously put on hold by people who **cannot read**. From the reasons given for hold: ' must include the desired behavior' - `check`; 'specific problem or error' - `check`; 'the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself' - `check`. We obviously have people on SO who vote to close questions out of spite or for other dubious reasons unrelated to the question itself. This is not a MCVE question.

Comment: Note to the readers: the actual reason for the error is not given in the accepted answer, but unveiled in comment https://stackoverflow.com/q/30769222#comment49623482_30769859 => stdin was put in non-blocking I/O mode by one of the program called by the menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your menu there are a few things that don't make sense. In each of your case statements you call:

```
(exec "./script1")
```

That is calling `./script1` as a command, not a separate script. Second since you are enclosing the line in parens `()`, you are forcing execution to take place in a **subshell** instead of the current shell.

Your use of `SELECTION` in `[ "$SELECTION" = "5" ]` appears to be uninitialized, (which I presume is the reason you have it wrapped in quotes). There is nothing wrong with quoting, but your values are `1-5`, so it isn't mandatory as long as it is initialized.

Your menu itself is fine. The fact is it fails to execute multiple times is the result of whatever you are doing in `(exec "./script1")`. Since you appear to be attempting to call a bash script from your `case` statement, the proper way to launch the scripts (if they are not made executable with `chmod 0755`) is to use `bash` instead of `exec`. If the scripts are not bash, or you want to generalize the call, then the use of `exec` will work as mentioned in the comments.

While there is nothing wrong with `until` (other than not being used commonly), I would suggest using `while`. Further, since you have multiple `echo` statements in a row, consider using a `here` statement to create a `heredoc` instead.

Indention of your code makes reading much easier and keeps the logic apparent. One caveat is with the `heredoc` and its closing delimiter. To indent the `heredoc` and its delimeter, they **must be indented with `TABS` not `SPACES`**. Further, the heredoc must be started with `<<-` instead of simply `<<` to take advantage of the `TAB` indention. (which is why I didn't broach the subject to begin with)

A slight rewrite could look something like the following. **Note:** the code below is `8-space` indented because SO converts `TABS` to `SPACES`, so to use the code with the indention shown, you will need to insure the whitespace preceding the code is `TAB` characters and not `SPACES` or it **will not run**:

```
declare -i SEL=0

while [ $SEL != 5 ]; do
        cat >&2 <<- MENU
          Enter a number to launch:
            1) Script 1
            2) Script 2
            3) Script 1 and Script 2
            4) Readme
            5) Exit
        MENU
        echo -n "  Launch: "
        read SEL
        case $SEL in
            1)  echo "./script1"
                ;;
            2)  echo "./script2"
                ;;
            3)  echo "./script1"
                echo "./script2"
                ;;
            4)  vi "readme.txt"
                ;;
            5)  exit 0
                ;;
            *)  echo "Error. Please enter a valid selection."
                ;;
        esac
done
```

You can choose whether you want to formally indent the `heredoc` or not. I prefer `4-space` indention, so I simply leave the `heredoc` opening and delimiter without indention to preserve the ability to allow **cut/paste** of the example. Your choice:

```
declare -i SEL=0

while [ $SEL != 5 ]; do
cat >&2 << MENU
  Enter a number to launch:
    1) Script 1
    2) Script 2
    3) Script 1 and Script 2
    4) Readme
    5) Exit
MENU
    echo -n "  Launch: "
    read SEL
    case $SEL in
        1)  exec "./script1"
            ;;
        2)  exec "./script2"
            ;;
        3)  exec "./script1"
            exec "./script2"
            ;;
        4)  vi "readme.txt"
            ;;
        5)  exit 0
            ;;
        *)  echo "Error. Please enter a valid selection."
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: There's actually one more problem. Judging from the option description "Readme" I suppose it's for informational purpose; then one should really use a pager like `less` rather than a text editor.

Comment: Agreed, unless he wants to edit it and add some of the output from `script1`, etc..

Comment: The addition of `bash` seems superfluous, and possibly erroneous.  `exec` would use whatever the shebang in these scripts says; so should the fixed script (what if they are Perl, Python, `sed`, Awk, Ruby etc scripts?)

Comment: Also, the indentation should be fixed -- the body of the loop should be indented, just to show the OP how to indent properly.

Comment: Fixed. I'm not sure the dissertation of `heredoc` indention was worth it, but to be 100% correct, I agree with your point.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your very helpful advice. I was able to get this working how I intended.

Comment: I also appreciate @David C. Rankin showing me exactly what was wrong and explaining the corrections. I learned a great deal from your response.

Comment: I would also like to add that the specific error - read: read error: 0: resource temporarily unavailable actually came from one of the scripts (script 1) using a TCL subscript which put stdin in blocking mode -0. Blocking mode was never set back to -1 so the stdin was unavailable to the user. The following script (script 2) had a while loop to validate user input and was constantly receive a whitespace "" as the input causing an infinite loop. Another helpful resource about this situation -http://www.codedisqus.com/0xyeUVUVUU/bash-shell-read-error-0-resource-temporarily-unavailable.html